# Reading file names inside .zip file

Tags: unicode, utf-8, zip

I am familiar with the .zip file format, and able to read the internal file table content so far.

The problem occurs with non-english characters in the file name.

The specification states that file names use OEM character set, yet sometimes I get UTF-8 representation and sometimes I get OEM represantation.

The specification states the "version made by" field should be in range 0-20, yet I get versions 31 and 63 which may or may not affect the character set.

Another related problem: When I read the "extra field" there is "up" (unicode path, id=0x7075) which suppose to store the utf-8 represantation of the filename, well, it starts with 5 redundant bytes before the actual utf-8 string (Created by WinRar), yet the other softwares seems to read it correctly.

Any input about the issue?

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date zip specification? The [current spec is 6.3.4 in 2014](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). Unicode filename support was [added in 6.3.0 in 2006](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.0.TXT) (see Appendix D). The "general purpose bit flag" in the file header tells you whether UTF-8 is being used or not, unless extra records 0x6375 and 0x7075 are used instead. By "5 redundant bytes" are you referring to the 1-byte Version and 4-byte CRC32 checksum that precede the UTF-8 data (see sections 4.6.8 and and 4.6.9)

Comment: Wow! This is what I have missed! Thank you!